# Calling iter() on an instance of my class doesn't create a 'snapshot' of its current values?

Tags: python, class, iteration

So I've created a custom class in Python that supports iteration using the `__iter__` method. My `__iter__` method is structured as a generator object, using `yield` to give each of the values in the instance of the class.

I'm finding that if I say something like `x = iter(my_instance)` and then edit the data stored in my instance, if I subsequently build a list out of `x`, I will find that that list contains the values that `my_class` currently has, rather than the values it had when I called `iter()`.

So my question is two-fold at this point. First of all, is that what is supposed to happen? If so, why does it work like that?

---

Above is the main thing, but if you really want to go above and beyond, keep reading. Now the reason I'm asking this question is that I've had to create this class as an assignment at university. My professor has provided a program that will run a bunch of tests on this class I created in order to give me a good idea of whether or not I've done it correctly the first time.

My program is passing every single check except the last one, which basically does what is described above. The problem is that it expects the list that is built from a previous call to `iter(my_object)` to reflect only values stored in `my_object` at the time that `iter()` was called on it.

My initial reaction after looking this over was that my professor intended to get a result similar to simply calling `list(my_object)`, but I'm the student here, so it seems much more likely I simply coded my `__iter__` method in some very strange way, which is causing this behavior. Or did Python change how the `iter()` function works recently?

---

I would prefer not to post my code, since it's for a class, and that could technically be considered cheating (I know that's stupid and unhelpful, sorry). However, I can link the specification, which is right [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/assignments/program2/program.html) (specifically part 1, the `Bag` class).

Comment: Your iterator and your class are using the same underlying list object for storage. This is why both of them will see a change when you modify the data.

Comment: If you want to "freeze" the iterator, you can explicitly convert it to a list (or some other consuming data type). Iterators are usually lazy, which explains why your's is having the described behavior.

Comment: When iterating over mutable objects (and your Bag is mutable), also iterators from the standard library will exhibit the same behavior: they will operate on the iterable in the current state, reflecting modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment appears to give you a strong hint as to how you should go about this

> Ensure that the iterator produces those values in the Bag at the time
>   the iterator starts executing; so mutating the Bag during iteration
>   will not affect what values it produces.
>
> Hint: Write this method as a call to a local generator, passing a copy
>   of the dictionary (covered in Friday's lecture in Week 4).

Comment: Oh man, I kept looking at the second part of that, and thinking it meant 'create a generator' and missing the first bit. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

As (I think) @Cyb3rFly3r was trying to say, the behavior of iterating over a mutable class that does this is highly discordant with the way it works for the container classes in the standard library — and would therefore be a somewhat debatable design choice to make on those grounds alone in the real world.

It also runs counter to probably one of the main reasons the concept of iterators was introduced into Python, which was to make creating separate copies of the contents of container objects so they could be iterated-over unnecessary.

Anyway, that's exactly what you'll need to do in your `__iter__()` method (and sounds like what is in the hint from Detail 11 of the [linked specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683469/calling-iter-on-an-instance-of-my-class-doesnt-create-a-snapshot-of-its-cur) shown in [Peter Gibson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36683561/355230) is suggesting, *copying* the dictionary that stores all the information in a `Bag` instance — be it a plain `dict`ionary, a `defaultdict`, or whatever).

You could optimize things (by minimizing the extra memory required for the copy and the ease of internally iterating of it) by creating an internal **`list`** of its contents rather than making a copy of the whole likely more-complex data structure. **Tip**: Doing this would probably be very similar to what you're going to need to do to implement the `__repr__()` method so its results look like:

**Bag(['a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd'])**

as shown in Detail 3 of the specification.

Since you've chosen not to post any code, it difficult to help you much further.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. After reading this and what Perter Gibson wrote it all makes sense. I just figured we must be being asked to use generator statements, since we've been learning that, I got sort of caught off guard by the idea of doing things a less efficient way.

Comment: You may still end up using what you call generator statements in your implementation — only they'll be iterating over the copy or alternative data structure you've decided to use to provide the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing.